# Problema para redirecionar com javascript (window.location.href)

Tags: javascript

Olá, desejo que usuarios só consigam acessar determinada area do site se tiverem uma senha de acesso.

meu código é esse:

```
function redirect() {
  var pass;
  pass = prompt("Qual a palavra mágica?");
  if (pass == "asdfouch") {
    window.location.href = '[link]';
  } 
  else {
    alert("Ops, desculpe mas você ainda não tem acesso ou digitou o código errado :/");
  }
}
```

Se digito a senha errada eu recebo o alerta, porem nada acontece ao digitar a senha correta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Além do **window.location.href** você pode usar **window.location.replace**

> Se você quiser simular alguém clicando em um link, use **`location.href`**
>
> Se você quiser simular um redirecionamento HTTP, use **`location.replace`**
>
> Fonte: [Como redirecionar para outra página?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage) ( Stack em Inglês )

```js
function redirect() {
  var pass;
  pass = prompt("Qual a palavra mágica?");
  if (pass == "asdfouch") {
     window.location.replace("https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered");
  } 
  else {
    alert("Ops, desculpe mas você ainda não tem acesso ou digitou o código errado :/");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Posso entrar?" onclick="redirect()">
```

Answer (score 0):

**O erro é: constante de cadeia não finalizada**

Essa linha

`alert("Ops, desculpe mas você ainda não tem acesso ou digitou o código 
        errado :/");`

parece estar quebrada!

```js
function redirect() {
  var pass;
  pass = prompt("Qual a palavra mágica?");
  if (pass == "asdfouch") {
    window.location.href = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered';
  } 
  else {
    alert("Ops, desculpe mas você ainda não tem acesso ou digitou o código errado :/");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="redirect()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: a quebra de linha foi erro na hora que eu estava digitando aqui no site apenas (infelizmente, pois teria resolvido o problema hahah)

Quanto ao botao no codigo html, ele usa esse mesmo atributo.

Comment: @FelipeAugusto não entendi, "digitando aqui no site", vc quer dizer que errou na formulação da pergunta e então o erro não é esse na sua aplicação? Que o erro ainda persiste? No executar da minha resposta está funcionando!

Comment: foi um erro apenas de formataçao aqui no proprio site. No programa a linha nao esta quebrada. Infelizmente o problema persiste.

Comment: o chamado da funçao no html é feito assim:   
<form method="POST" onclick="redirect()">
<input type="submit" value="Posso entrar?">

Comment: Ai está o motivo, você pode fazer assim: `<input type="button" value="Posso entrar?" onclick="redirect()">` sem o uso do `form`

Comment: Funcionou, aplicando essa mudança. obg!

Comment: @FelipeAugusto a minha resposta estava correta independentemente de vc ter me dito que estava usando onclick no form. Se o onclick está no botão não poderia estar no form evidentemente. Nas proximas perguntas procure postar o codigo tal como ele está na sua aplicação, isso é, procure não gerar mais erros na postagem da sua pergunta para não dar trabalho extra sem necessidade a quem quer lhe ajudar